# Fragment transaction is lagging when adding (or re entering) a fragment while adding data to a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have some lag related issues with my fragment transactions, when switching to a fragment that asre showing `recyclerviews` with data. The more data and complex it is, the more the transaction is lagging.

I have no issue regarding the scroll performance etc. Only the transaction animation (slide in this case).

The problem is only present when I give the `recyclerview` data in some of the methods of the **fragment lifecycle**, like `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`...

The only time I can get rid og the lag, is if I wait until the `fragment transaction` is complete (animation done) and then give the data to the `recyclerview`. However, I don't think this looks very good when it animates a blank screen in and then add the data to the `recyclerview` afterwards.

Is there anyway I can give the `recyclerview` data before the transaction animation is done without the lag?

The transaction part is really simple:

```
val fragmentTransaction:        FragmentTransaction?    = supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()

fragmentTransaction?.setCustomAnimations(animationTheme.screenRootEnter(), animationTheme.screenRootExit(), animationTheme.screenRootPopEnter(),animationTheme.screenRootPopExit())
fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
fragmentTransaction?.addToBackStack(tag)
fragmentTransaction?.commit()
```

The interesting part is the part where I give data to the `recyclerview`:

```
fun setData(items: ArrayList<ListItem>) {
    this.mItems     = items
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, items.size)
}
```

(As mentioned, this causes the lag when called from `onCreateView` or similar)

Comment: what data are you loading in the recyclerView? I feel there is lots of strain on the UI thread.

Comment: Well, it is different view types that I load. A combination og text, drawables etc. However, I did try to remove all of the heavy stuff for the  purpose of testing so only simple textviews were left and still saw the lag. Not as much, but it was still there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to late for answer.
You shouldn't make a big work on the UI thread while doing View creation.
You can override `onCreateAnimator()` in your fragment and find out when the animation ends. Then you can add your data in `RecyclerView` adapter.
You can show a `ProgressBar` in view creation time and hide after progress after data was loaded.

```
@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    if (nextAnim != 0x0) {
        Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), nextAnim);
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // We just need know animation ending when fragment entered and no need to know when exited
                if (enter) {
                    // here add data to recyclerview adapter
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        });
        return animator;
    }
    return null;
}
```